# What does PRIVATE_CONFIG=tm.ipc mean and how to generate tm.ipc file?

Tags: blockchain, quorum

i have tried the below command using PRIVATE_CONFIG=ignore.Can anyone help me to find some explanation regarding how tm.ipc is generated and what is its use

```
PRIVATE_CONFIG=tm.ipc nohup geth --datadir new-node-1 --nodiscover --verbosity 5 --networkid 31337 --raft --raftport 50000 --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcport 22000 --rpcapi admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3,quorum,raft --emitcheckpoints --port 21000 2>>node.log &
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tm.ipc socket file is created by the transaction manager (Constellation or Tessera).

It's used by Quorum to communicate with the transaction manager for private transactions and Quorum expects `PRIVATE_CONFIG` to specify the location of the sokcet file.

If you are only interested in public transactions then you don't need a transaction manager, hence the `PRIVATE_CONFIG=ignore` setting.
Documentation for this can be found [here](http://docs.goquorum.com/en/latest/Getting%20Started/Getting-Started-From-Scratch/#adding-privacy-transaction-manager)